# Having an issue with Firebase 4.0.4 and iOS 11 - Beta 4

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

After compilation (xCode 9 - Beta 4) of the Firebase Messaging QS code sample, on the run of the sample on a device running (iOS 11 - Beta 4) we receive the following error.

MessagingExampleSwift[354:15228] TIC TCP Conn Failed [1:0x1c4361e00]: 1:50 Err(50)
MessagingExampleSwift[354:15228] Task .<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1009 [1:50])
MessagingExampleSwift[354:15226] Task .<1> finished with error - code: -1009

Running the same code on a device running (iOS 10.3) does not receive the error.

The result is that we cannot retrieve an FCM Token correctly.

Does anyone know of a compatibility issue between Firebase 4.0.4 and iOS 11?

We have added an issue to the GIT Repo for the Messaging QS

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/309

Comment: -1009 = `NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet`